# Javascript doesn't return a correct value

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on HTML and Javascript.

I have a label which you can see below

```
<label for="optGender">Gender: </label> 
<input id="optGender" type="radio" name="optGender" value="F" onclick="changeGender(this.value)">
Female
<br>
<input id="optGender" type="radio" name="optGender" value="M" onclick="changeGender(this.value)">
Male
<br>
Where do you want to live?
<br>
<select id="txtCity" name="lstCity" size="5">
<option value="06">Ankara</option>
<option value="34">Istanbul</option>
<option value="35">Izmir</option>
<option value="27">Gaziantep</option>
</select>
<br>
```

and in my javascript file I have this function to check whether its checked or not

```
function changeGender(whichOne){

    var gender = document.forms["ProcessInfo"]["optGender"].value;
    var optGender = document.getElementById("optGender");
    var txtCity = document.getElementById("txtCity");

    if ( !document.getElementById('optGender').checked )
    {
    errMessage += "Please select your gender.\n";
    document.getElementById('optGender').checked = false;
    }
    //if ( gender == "M" ) { alert("lol");}

}
```

When I select "Female" button, it works, doesn't give an error. But when I choose male, it gives me an error that I havent selected any option. What is wrong with that?

Edit * What I actually want to do is, If I select F the list will have the cities which starts with I, for M its going to be G. I can easily handle this part, but I'm stuck at easiest part.

Comment: Provide jsFiddle examle [here](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have the same ID for both inputs.  That won't work...
Document.getelementbyid returns the first instance it finds the id you provided, which is the male input.  I think what you might want here is a select instead of an input...

Give me a second and I'll modify your code for you.

```
<label for="optGender">Gender: </label> 
<input id="Female" type="radio" name="optGender" value="F" onclick="changeGender(this)">
Female
<br>
<input id="Male" type="radio" name="optGender" value="M" onclick="changeGender(this)">
Male
<br>
Where do you want to live?
<br>
<select id="txtCity" name="lstCity" size="5">
<option value="06">Ankara</option>
<option value="34">Istanbul</option>
<option value="35">Izmir</option>
<option value="27">Gaziantep</option>
</select>
<br>


function changeGender(whichOne){
    var gender = whichOne.value;
    if ( gender == "M" ) { alert("lol");}
    if ( gender == "F" ) { alert("wat");}

}
```

Comment: Edited my html file sir, I will remove options from "txtCity" but I still can't handle the select issue. It works for only female. @deweyredman

Comment: Alright...try that out.  Let me know if you run into anything.

Comment: It works like a charm sir, If both cases == null, it gives an error for both cases now. Thanks! ( And /laughed at `("wat")` part :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your radio's ID and keep the name. It'll work

Comment: When I change the ID, it doesn't select the radio button

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have 2 elements with the same `id` in `HTML`. You have 2 elements with same id ie `optGender`.